# How to retain scope value, when scope is destroyed between link and controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a scenario, where there are two tabs on a page: Is there a way to retain the values of `x`  ?

I have tried with `$rootscope.$on`, and it worked. Is there any other way to implement it?

```
angular.module('x', []).directive('y', function() {

      return: {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: '',
        scope: {},
        controller: function($scope) {
          console.log($scope.test); // the value is x when i am on the      //same tab, the value is undefined when i  switch the tab 
        },
        link: function(scope) {
          scope.test = 'x';
        }

      });
```

Comment: You should use a service. They're useful for sharing info across all the app "components"

Comment: Thought of service, but its like  there are thousands of values , and will it impact the performance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your info is huge, one option you can use is to save it in *localStorage*. Please see [localStorage info](http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-local-storage). You save the info when scope is destroyed and then retrieve it later when needed.